# EF4 Cast DynamicProxies to underlying object

Tags: c#, serialization, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm using Entity Framework 4 with POCO template.

I have a List where MyObject are dynamic proxies. I want to use the XmlSerializer to serialize this list, but I don't want them serialized as DynamicProxies but as the underlaying POCO object.

I know about ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled, but I do not want to use that. I just want to know how to cast a proxy object to it's underlaying POCO to serialize.

Comment: If you are using WCF Services, this article should help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx

Comment: Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770369/get-underlying-entity-object-from-entity-framework-proxy/25774651#25774651).

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same issue today and used [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to solve it. It's as simple as:

```
var dynamicProxyMember = _repository.FindOne<Member>(m=>m.Id = 1);
var member = new Member().InjectFrom(dynamicProxyMember) as Member;
```

Comment: Is the Member attached to the DbContext?

Answer (score 2):

Ill dig these old bones up by offering a solution that helped me. Hopefully, it will help someone that reads it.

So, there are actually two solutions. If you don't want lazy loading you can always turn off dynamic proxies and that will give you just the entitiy:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false
    }

    public DbSet<NiceCat> NiceCats {get; set;}
    public DbSet<CrazyCat> CrazyCats {get; set;}
    public DbSet<MeanCat> MeanCats {get; set;}

}
```

The other solution is to use the ObjectContext to get the original entity type the proxy stands in for:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var meanAssCat = context.MeanCats.Find(CurrentCat.Id)
    var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(meanAssCat.GetType());
}
```

Comment: ObjectContext.GetObjectType returns the entity's Type, not an entity object.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to turn ProxyCreation off, you are stuck DynamicProxy objects wherever you put virtual keyword for object property (EF Context inherits your object and replaces virtual properties with DynamicProxy objects). These DynamicProxy objects do not inherit from your POCO entities, they just have same properties and can be used instead of your POCO. If you really must to convert to POCO object (and I don't believe that someone will come up with a way to cast it), you may try to workaround by writing copy constructor which will copy all properties from passed argument (not very smart from performance standpoint, but what you have to do, you have to do), or maybe using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute` in parent object which contains your dynamic proxy instead of poco to tell serializer how to serialize virtual property (into which type).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I've created a somewhat generic solution to this problem. I found this old question while searching for a solution so I figured I'd share my solution here to help whoever may be stubbing his or her toe on the same problem.

I ran into the same problem: I needed to get some stuff from Entity Framework, and then use ASP.NET Web Api to serialize it to XML. I've tried disabling lazy loading and proxy creation and using Include(), but on anything but the most basic class hierarchy that led to gigantic SQL queries that took several minutes to execute. I found that using lazy loading and referencing each property recursively was many, many times faster than loading the tree all at once, so I figured I'd need a way to lazy load everything, get it in the form of a POCO, and then serialize it.

I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25774651/1621861) by Gert Arnold as the basis for this solution, and then worked from there.

I've created an Unproxy method in the DBContext that takes a (proxied) class instance (something you'd get back from DbContext.Find(id) for instance) and returns that entity as an actual POCO type, with each property, sub-property etc. fully loaded and ready for serialization.

The Unproxy method and some readonly fields:

```
readonly Type ignoreOnUnproxyAttributeType = typeof(IgnoreOnUnproxyAttribute);
readonly string genericCollectionTypeName = typeof(ICollection<>).Name;

public T UnProxy<T>(T proxyObject) where T : class
{
    // Remember the proxyCreationEnabled value 
    var proxyCreationEnabled = Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;

    try
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        T poco = Entry(proxyObject).CurrentValues.ToObject() as T; // Convert the proxy object to a POCO object. This only populates scalar values and such, so we have to load other properties separately.

        // Iterate through all properties in the POCO type
        foreach (var property in poco.GetType().GetProperties())  
        {
            // To prevent cycles, like when a child instance refers to its parent and the parent refers to its child, we'll ignore any properties decorated with a custom IgnoreOnUnproxyAttribute.
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(property, ignoreOnUnproxyAttributeType))
            {
                property.SetValue(poco, null);
                continue;
            }

            dynamic proxyPropertyValue = property.GetValue(proxyObject); // Get the property's value from the proxy object

            if (proxyPropertyValue != null)
            {
                // If the property is a collection, get each item in the collection and set the value of the property to a new collection containing those items.
                if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.Name == genericCollectionTypeName)
                {                            
                    SetCollectionPropertyOnPoco<T>(poco, property, proxyPropertyValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the property is not a collection, just set the value of the POCO object to the unproxied (if necessary) value of the proxy object's property.
                    if (proxyPropertyValue != null)
                    {
                        // If the type of the property is one of the types in your model, the value needs to be unproxied first. Otherwise, just set the value as is.
                        var unproxiedValue = (ModelTypeNames.Contains(property.PropertyType.Name)) ? SafeUnproxy(proxyPropertyValue) : proxyPropertyValue;
                        property.SetValue(poco, unproxiedValue);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        return poco; // Return the unproxied object
    }
    finally
    {
        // Zet ProxyCreationEnabled weer terug naar de oorspronkelijke waarde.
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
    }
}
```

ModelTypeNames is a property I've added to my DBContext that simply returns all the types used in the model. That way we'll know which types we need to unproxy:

```
private Collection<string> modelTypeNames;

private Collection<string> ModelTypeNames
{
    get
    {
        if (modelTypeNames == null)
        {
            // We'll figure out all the EF model types by simply returning all the type arguments of every DbSet<> property in the dbContext.
            modelTypeNames = new Collection<string>(typeof(VerhaalLokaalDbContext).GetProperties().Where(d => d.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DbSet<>).Name).SelectMany(d => d.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments).Select(t => t.Name).ToList());
        }

        return modelTypeNames;
    }
}
```

To deal with ICollection<> properties, we need to first instantiate a new generic collection (I'm using reflection to create a HashSet<> with the right type argument), iterate through all the values, unproxy each value and add it to the new HashSet, which is then used as the value for the POCO's property.

```
private void SetCollectionPropertyOnPoco<T>(T poco, PropertyInfo property, dynamic proxyPropertyValue) where T : class
{
    // Create a HashSet<> with the correct type
    var genericTypeArguments = ((System.Type)(proxyPropertyValue.GetType())).GenericTypeArguments;
    var hashSetType = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(genericTypeArguments);
    var hashSet = Activator.CreateInstance(hashSetType);

    // Iterate through each item in the collection, unproxy it, and add it to the hashset.
    foreach (var item in proxyPropertyValue)
    {
        object unproxiedValue = SafeUnproxy(item);
        hashSetType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(hashSet, new[] { unproxiedValue }); // Add the unproxied value to the new hashset
    }

    property.SetValue(poco, hashSet); // Set the new hashset as the poco property value.        
}
```

Note that I'm calling SafeUnproxy rather than Unproxy. This is because of a weird issue with type inference. Usually when you pass a proxy object to Unproxy(), type inference will infer that T is the POCO type you actually want, not the type of the dataproxy (the one that looks like YourModelPocoType_D0339E043A5559D04303M3033 etc). However, occasionally it *does* infer T as the dataproxy type, which blows up the

```
T poco = Entry(proxyObject).CurrentValues.ToObject() as T;
```

line, because the poco object can't be cast to the proxy type, causing the as operator to return null. To fix this, SafeUnproxy calls the Unproxy method with an explicit type parameter rather than relying on inference: it checks the type of the parameter you pass it, and if the namespace is System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies, it'll use the type's BaseType (which in the case of a dynamicproxy type is the corresponding POCO type) as the generic type argument.

```
private object SafeUnproxy(dynamic item)
{
    // ProxyCreation is off, so any reference or collection properties may not yet be loaded. We need to make sure we explicitly load each property from the db first.
    ExplicitlyLoadMembers(item);

    // Figure out the right type to use as the explicit generic type argument
    var itemType = item.GetType();
    Type requiredPocoType = (itemType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies") ?
                                                                itemType.BaseType :
                                                                itemType;

    // Call Unproxy using an explicit generic type argument
    var unproxiedValue = typeof(VerhaalLokaalDbContext).GetMethod("UnProxy").MakeGenericMethod(requiredPocoType).Invoke(this, new[] { item });
    return unproxiedValue;
}
```

Making sure each property is loaded from the database is a matter of iterating through the properties of the object and checking IsLoaded:

```
private void ExplicitlyLoadMembers(dynamic item)
{
    foreach (var property in ((Type)item.GetType()).GetProperties())
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Entry(item);
        var dbMemberEntry = dbEntityEntry.Member(property.Name);

        // If we're dealing with a Reference or Collection entity, explicitly load the properties if necessary.
        if (dbMemberEntry is DbReferenceEntry)
        {
            if (!dbEntityEntry.Reference(property.Name).IsLoaded)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.Reference(property.Name).Load();
            }
        }
        else if (dbMemberEntry is DbCollectionEntry)
        {
            if (!dbEntityEntry.Collection(property.Name).IsLoaded)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.Collection(property.Name).Load();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the IgnoreOnUnproxyAttribute used to avoid cycles:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class IgnoreOnUnproxyAttribute : Attribute
{        
}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

public Story Get(int storyId)
{
    var lazyStory = db.Stories.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == storyId);
    var unproxied = db.UnProxy(lazyStory);

    return unproxied;
}
```

Performance isn't spectacular due to all the reflection going on, but execution time is on average only slightly (i.e. less than a second) longer than when lazy loading an entity, iterating through all its properties, and then serializing the dynamicproxy itself. Also, it's much, much faster than when using Include() which is dreadfully slow and error-prone.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue in EF 5. I was trying to serialize my entity objects to XML. @Koreyam s answer gave me a hint. I developed it little bit more.
Somewhere in my code i was calling the serializer like this

```
string objXML = EntitySerializer.Serialize(entity);
```

Serialize method is generic. So method header is like this :

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T tObj) where T : class, new()
```

So in my method body i use [value injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) :

```
T obj = new T().InjectFrom(tObj) as T;
```

it just solved my issue for all of my entitites.