# C# Clone System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies to the actual (non proxied) class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, dynamic-proxy, cloning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EF4 Cast DynamicProxies to underlying object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641795/ef4-cast-dynamicproxies-to-underlying-object)

I'm trying to figure out how to clone or convert a System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies into it's actual class. Eg:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Currency_F4008E27DE_etc is the proxy class
MyApp.Entities.Currency is the real class
```

All of the classes in MyApp.Entities inherit from BaseEntity, so I tried to do the converting there:

```
public abstract partial class BaseEntity
{
    public T ShallowCopy<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone() as T;
    }
    // other BaseEntity properties not relevent here
}
```

And then converting the DynamicProxies into the real class:

```
// this returns a DynamicProxies class
Currency currency = LookupDefaultCurrency(); 
// this one needs to return a Entities.Currency class 
// (but currently returns a DynamicProxies class too
Currency pocoCurrency = (Currency)currency.ShallowCopy<Currency>();
HttpRuntime.Cache[key] = pocoCurrency;
```

The reason for this is that I want to remove all Entity Framework tracking and etc from this object and just store its plain (POCO) properties in the cache.  And I will need to be able to do this for all 100 or so Entity classes, so it has to be reasonably generic - without manually saying object1.foo = object2.foo for every single property.

Comment: Why you didn't turn off proxy generation as you asked in previous question?

Comment: Turns out that is not what I needed.  I do need them to be proxies (with all the tracking etc) for most of the time.  But when caching for later read only use it needs to be a non proxy object see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688772/c-entity-framework-using-only-one-objectcontext-per-httpcontext

Comment: You can turn off proxy creation selectively for some context instances or even queries so Imho you should be fine with turning off proxies only for loading your currencies.

Comment: I'm using a repository - service pattern, so the actual objectcontext is not accessible, it is two layers separated from the code that calls _service.Get() which calls repository.Get() which calls objectcontext.asQueryable().Where(..etc..)

Comment: In such case you need special method like `GetUnproxied()`. Architecture should not demand how would you retrieve data. If you need special method simply expose it. Generic approach is fairy tale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this article](http://www.csharp411.com/c-object-clone-wars/) is helpful. It discusses several methods for cloning data. I'm not sure if these methods can be used to convert an object of type A to an object of type B. But it's definitely worth a try.

I would be very interested in the outcome of this, since [this NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/CacheManagement) also uses the generic repository pattern and memcached to address the same caching technique and your problem seems to be same there when deserializing data.

Comment: @JK Could you provide which method made it work for you, I'm very interested, since I have the same issue in my project.